# How to get a docker history from an image that has not been pulled yet?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Since [`docker history`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/) is great to see how an image has been created or if it's applicable, it seems to only available for local, already pulled images.

Q: **Is there a way to get a peak into a docker image without the need of downloading it?**

Perfectly it would fit my needs if I would be able to inspect the "Dockerfile", but I bet this is more impossible than just looking at the history of an image ;)